# Using a comparator on ArrayList<E>

Tags: java, comparator

I've been trying to sort an `ArrayList<E>` with a custom comparator shown below

```
@Override
public int compare(Dog d1, Dog d2){
    return Integer.compare(d1.tired, d2.tired);
};
```

Now this is all I want to get working before I move on:

```
public static <E> ArrayList<E> listBiggest(ArrayList<E> list) {
    Dog dogcomparator = new Dog();
    Collections.sort(list, dogcomparator);
}
```

Although I can't sort the list because it's of apparently list has no objects which conform to the comparator type although the list is all of that type or objects which extend it.

I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong.

The error I am getting is

```
Error:(15, 20) java: no suitable method found for sort(java.util.ArrayList<E>,Dog)
method java.util.Collections.<T>sort(java.util.List<T>) is not applicable
  (cannot infer type-variable(s) T
    (actual and formal argument lists differ in length))
method java.util.Collections.<T>sort(java.util.List<T>,java.util.Comparator<? super T>) is not applicable
  (inference variable T has incompatible bounds
    equality constraints: E
    lower bounds: Dog,java.lang.Object)
```

Am I missing something fundamental that I don't know about? Is there even enough information to get the gist of what I am trying to ask?

Comment: Are you confusing comparator with comparable? On `Dog dogcomparator = new Dog();`, that's not a dog Comparator, that's just a Dog.

Comment: What is the error you’re getting? Is there a stacktrace? If not, show with input and output what do you expect and what you get.

Comment: @Vitruvius I have a compare method as part of my Dog class. My assumption would be giving it a dog object would use it's comparator.

Comment: @AbhijitSarkar I have included the error I have gotten. I expext my ArrayList<E> to be sorted with the comparator I have created

Answer (score 1):

You’ve a `List<E>` which you want to sort using a `Comparator<Dog>`. The compiler doesn’t know what’s `E`; for all it knows, `E` could be a `Person`.
If you’re sure it’s a list of dogs, cast it.

Comment: Ok, that makes a lot of sense why it isn't working. Now, is there a way I can do that before I try to sort the list so that I can keep the generic list until this specific method is called?

Comment: @Yalnix I’m not sure what you’re asking. I suggest you pause copy-pasting code you found on the internet and pick up a Java book.

Answer (score 0):

Change the signature of the method. If everything in there is required to be some kind of `Dog` then declare that.

```
public static <E extends Dog> List<E> listBiggest(List<E> list) {
```

It's better to declare `List` (the interface that `ArrayList` implements) the same way that `Collections.sort` does, as well. This will let the method be used for any sort of list, not just that one specific implementation.

You'll also need to add a `return` to the method, or make the method return type `void`.

Comment: There's no need for that method in the first place, but that's another matter.